# A simple inhomogeneous wave equation with non-constant coefficients.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations

Consider $$\frac{\partial p(x,t)}{\partial t} + u(x) \frac{\partial p(x,t)}{\partial x} + \frac{du(x)}{dx} p(x,t) = 0$$
where $u(x)$ and $\frac{du(x)}{dx}$ are known and well-defined, together with

- Boundary condition: $p(x,t)$ is bounded as $x\rightarrow\infty$.
- Initial condition: any sufficiently smooth function $G(x)$.

---

Is there any wave to solve this PDE analytically? This PDE is simplified from a physical problem, solution $p(x,t)$ is always sufficiently smooth and bounded.

Answer (score 1):

You can solve first order linear partial differential equations using the [method of characteristics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Method_of_characteristics). I advise you to try it out and see how far you get. If you get stuck at any point, share your attempts, and maybe someone can assist you based on your work.